# Stumbling Block Inventor iProperty doesn't exist

Tags: vba, textbox, autodesk-inventor

I should start out with this is my first attempt at a vba user form.

I Have some simple code to fill a user form (pulling from Inventor Custom iProperties) the problem I am running into and made a false assumption (that if the property didn't exist it would be ignored) so now I get an error. oProSet1 & oProSet2 work perfectly (Those iProperties will always have a value) oProSet3 Throws an error, I am guessing because the "Setup Time" property doesn't exist & Isn't required (in this case). The code asterisks is my attempt and fail to use an if statement.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

' Get the active document.
Dim oDoc As Document
Set oDoc = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument

' Get the custom property set.
Dim oPropSet As PropertySet
Set oPropSet = oDoc.PropertySets.Item( _
"Inventor User Defined Properties")

Dim oPropSet1 As Property
Set oPropSet1 = oPropSet("Operation 1 Work Center 1")

 ' Set the value of the property.
TextBox1.Value = oPropSet1.Value

Dim oPropSet2 As Property
Set oPropSet2 = oPropSet("Operation 1 Machine Code 1")

 ' Set the value of the property.
TextBox2.Value = oPropSet2.Value

*Dim oPropSet3 As Property
Set oPropSet3 = oPropSet("Operation 1 Setup Time 1")
If oPropSet3("Operation 1 Setup Time 1") Is Nothing Then
 ' Set the value of the property.
 oPropSet3.Value = ""
 Else TextBox3.Value = oPropSet3.Value*
```

Comment: Are you referring to the proprietary AutoDesk Inventor Custom iProperties? https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Inventor-Help/files/GUID-15D16AE5-9A56-49E5-B899-6886423DFB26-htm.html

Comment: "now I get an error" - what error do you get and on which line specifically?  You can try ignoring the error `On Error Resume Next: Set oPropSet3 = oPropSet("Operation 1 Setup Time 1"): On Error Goto 0`  and then testing for `Nothing` to see if the property was found.

Comment: This is the error: And debug highlights in Yellow Set oPropSet3 = oPropSet("Operation 1 Setup Time 1")  Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Item' of object 'PropertySet' failed

Comment: The syntax looks a little strange to me.  I would try `If oPropSet3 Is Nothing Then`.  However, even if you get past that line, `oPropSet3.Value = ""` will fail because the object is Nothing.

Comment: Hi Tim Williams, Dim oPropSet3 As Property
    On Error Resume Next:
    Set oPropSet3 = oPropSet("Operation 1 Setup Time 1")
    ' Set the value of the property.
    TextBox3.Value = oPropSet3.Value
    On Error GoTo 0  Works Perfectly! Thank you! Brent

Answer (score 1):

I would try like this:

```vb
Dim oPropSet3 As Property

On Error Resume Next   'ignore error if missing
Set oPropSet3 = oPropSet("Operation 1 Setup Time 1")
On Error Goto 0        'stop ignoring errors

If oPropSet3 Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Property not found"
Else
    Debug.Print oPropSet3.Value 
End If
```